# What is the name of this disciple of Jesus in the English language?

Tags: disciple

What is the English name of St. Pathrose who is a disciple of Jesus in the Malayalam liturgy?

Answer (score 6):

According to the chart on [this page](http://www.rocksea.org/kerala-christian-names-origin-english-equivalents/), the English equivalent of the Malayam "Pathrose" is "Peter".

Comment: Please be informed that the names of Jesus,Mary, Joseph and the saints , as used in Malayalam liturgy , which is celebrated in the southern Indian state of Kerala, and by the people of Kerala all over the world, are nearer than are their English counterparts, to the original names due to Kerala's proximity to Syrian language . For instance, Yesu, Mariam, Ouseph , Thoma, Yacob  and Yohannan.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Thank you for that insight; we learn something new every day. (Off I go to take a longer look at that faith community ...)

Comment: That is great! You can log on to:  'Kerala State Central Library Rarebooks online ' and find many topics on Syrian Christians of India.